# Client-side React with Webpack - custom configuration via Parameters

Tags: reactjs

I have used `create-react-app` to create a new React project. I'm pretty much done and want to deploy the app as a JS plug-in running in the browser.

In the code `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Comments articleId="123" />, document.getElementById('comments'));
```

is after been built compiled into `main.xxxx.chunk.js`:

```
[...] c.a.render(s.a.createElement(R,{articleId:123}),document.getElementById("comments"))}},[[21,2,1]]]);
```

But I want to take the value over somehow as a parameter:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div id="comments">Rendering comments...</div>
<script>var articleId = 123;</script>
...
<script src="/assets/js/comments/main.xxxx.chunk.js"></script>
```

Is something like that possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have found:

```
//index.js
const commentsDiv = document.getElementById('comments');
const articleId = commentsDiv.getAttribute('articleId')

ReactDOM.render(<Comments articleId={articleId} />, commentsDiv);
```

Then render a HTML element with the attribute:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div id="comments" articleid="123">Rendering comments...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make articleid as a global value in html.

```
window.articleid=123
```

and then inside react call window.articleid to get the id.

Comment: This wouldn't work in case there are more than one plug-ins on the page...